# What has happened to this oil?

Tags: storage, spoilage

I recently purchased some sun-dried tomatoes in oil. However a few days in the fridge and they look like this despite being unopened.

[image]

I regularly buy these tomatoes and store them in the same way. Can anyone suggest what might have happened?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oil solidifies at cold temperature.

In the case of olive oil, it [does so at 37F](https://www.oliveoilsource.com/definition/freezing-point-olive-oil).

It takes a few minutes to get back to liquid state, either by leaving it on the counter or putting the jar in warm water.

Comment: So my fridge is just too cold! 

Comment: not necessarily; it should be below 40F (https://www.fda.gov/consumers/consumer-updates/are-you-storing-food-safely)

Comment: In which case it looks like it’s too warm normally! Either way it’s the wrong temperature for this oil.

Comment: Temp and time required for olive oil to go solid varies from batch to batch. The stuff should liquefy again if you warm it gently.

Comment: @Max 40F **or below**

Comment: This just happened to me and surprised me too.  Canola does not solidify in the fridge.  Sunflower does just a little bit.  Olive totally solidified and I had to run the bottle under hot water to pour it out.

Answer (score 0):

Had they been packaged in coconut oil it could look like that just by sitting in an air conditioned room as it solidifies at a steamy 70 degrees Fahrenheit.

Comment: Have you ever seen tomatoes packed in coconut oil?